# Struggling to understand orm autoManageSession

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, cfml, coldfusion-11

I'm having a hard time understanding the exact implications of setting 
 `autoManageSession` to false.

The docs say that if it is set it to false then "the application is responsible for managing flushing, clearing, or closing of the session".

So what are the practical implications to this? Does wrapping my ORM code in transactions take care of everything for me? What do I need to do manually that CF would have done automatically for me if I had this setting enabled?